# Detection of rotating objects using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, rotation, matlab-cvst, opticalflow

I have a video sequence of a cyclist moving and I need to detect the rotating wheels, Is there any way using MATLAB and image processing rotating region can be detected?

Comment: Matlab is a general-purpose programming tool. You can implement an image-processing algorithm with Matlab.

Comment: Yes you can. 1.- tart learing Image processing tools 2.- Start learning Matlab examples on image processing 3.-Have an idea of how you want to do it 4.-Try to implement it 5.- Fail and come to stackoverflow for answers (or win and you dont need to come! :D). My point is, to ask in stackoverflow you need first those 4 pre-steps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [training a cascade object detector](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/train-a-cascade-object-detector.html) to detect bicycle wheels in general.  You would need to label wheels in a lot of images, which you can do using the [Training Image Labeler app](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/label-images-for-classification-model-training.html).

Then, once you've detected a wheel, you try using optical flow to see if it is rotating. Or you can see if it is moving across the field of view, and just assume that it is rotating. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Dima, I owe you a lot...Thank you

Comment: In that case, you may want to vote up my answers... ;) Maybe even accept some of them. ;)